# Trouble working out whether one attribute of an object is greater that another attribute of that object

Tags: javascript, object, syntax

I am comparing two attributes of the same object to work out which one is larger, if one is larger then it sets another attribute to True.. else it sets it to false.

Here is my function:

```
country.prototype.cure = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i<this.diseases.length; i++)
  {
    console.log(this.health);
    console.log(this.diseases[i].cureLevel); 
    if (this.heatlh >= this.diseases[i].cureLevel)
  {
    this.diseases[i].cured = true;
    createDiseaseTable();
   }
    else
   {
       this.diseases[i].cured = false;
   }
 }
}
```

NOTE: this.health = 39000000  and this.diseases[i].cureLevel = 2500000

The problem is that whenever I run the function, despite this.health being larger it will always miss the if and go straight to the else...

Comment: Did you really spell it "heatlh" instead of "health" in your actual code?

Comment: Yeah you are right I spelt it wrong in this function... It's been a long day.. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
country.prototype.cure = function(){
  for (var i = 0; i<this.diseases.length; i++)
  {
    var a=parseInt(this.health);
    var b=parseInt(this.diseases[i].cureLevel);
    if (a >= b)
  {
    this.diseases[i].cured = true;
    createDiseaseTable();
   }
    else
   {
       this.diseases[i].cured = false;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` would only be useful if the property values were strings instead of numbers; there's no indication that that's the case in the OP, though of course it might be true.

Comment: I don't see any other possible mistake. I might be wrong, that's why it reads try this.